# What does self-preservation stem from?

Tags: ecology, behaviour

Self-preservation, or preservation anyway, probably happens throughout the animal kingdom, and perhaps through the plant kingdom as well (some plants/trees, apparently, produce chemicals to repel bugs).

Where does self-preservation stem from? Is it only about a biochemical imbalance?

Comment: Could you expand on your question a bit please? I cannot understand what you are asking here.

Comment: self-preservation in what sense?

Comment: Saving one's own life by avoiding starvation/discomfort(extremes of temperatures for instance)

Answer (score 2):

This is a prototypical case of evolution by natural selection. Any trait that prevents the organism from being eaten or destroyed will probably make that organism more likely to reproduce* than similar organisms that do not have that trait**. This results in self-preservation traits becoming more prevalent in the population and eventually ubiquitous.

* Or they reproduce more, or are able to provide for their offspring better, etc. Self-preservation behaviors that reduce reproductive success are not selected for and generally aren't common (unless they are a special case of some general trait that has a net reproductive benefit).

** Assuming that the trait is reproductively favorable after considering any trade-offs such as increased energy expenditure.

Comment: I would argue procreation is a side-effect ...

Comment: A side effect of what?